# Fr language in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, language

We are using Google Analytics for our portal. In the language metric we see fr-fr and fr. What's the difference between fr-fr and fr in Google Analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/02/12/languages-report-google-analytics/

Essentially, 'fr' is French (as a language setting in the browser as chosen by the user) and 'fr-fr' mean French in France (paired with the language setting).

Like 'en-us' means English from the US and 'en-gb' means English from the UK.

Hope that helps.